# Append new column based on existing colum Dataset Spark-Java

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I'm Using Java-Spark.

I have JSON data was loaded to `Dataset<Row>` object as follow:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().json(jsonSet);
Dataset<Row> dfSelect = df.select(cols);//Where cols is Column[]
```

My JSON as table looks like:

```
ColA    ColB
 2       3
 1       2
 3       1
```

I want to create a new column that calculate ColA + ColC value to make the final table to be like:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
 2       3       5
 1       2       3  
 3       1       4
```

How can I do it with My `dfSelect` Object?

```
dfSelect.withColumn("ColC", ?);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Column's [**plus**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#plus-java.lang.Object-) function:

```
Dataset<Row> newDs = dfSelect.withColumn("ColC",dfSelect.col("ColA").plus(dfSelect.col("ColB")).cast(IntegerType));
```